# Automatically update symbology classes when data changes (ArcGIS Pro layer)

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

Given an feature layer with a text column called 'name' in ArcGIS Pro 2.8, I would like to style this layer on this column.

When I add or remove features, or when I change the attribute in the column name, the symbology remains fixed. I could update it manually by clicking "Add unlisted values". Is there a way to dynamically insert the symbology classes based on the present values in the "name" column?

Comment: Not without developing a script and then running it, it will be quicker and simpler to continue as you are unless you are adding many values.